# Erro ao gradle build na API do PagSeguro - Java

Tags: java, api

Estou tentanto implementar a API do Pag Seguro no meu sistema, estava olhando o passo a passo que ele pede para baixar o repositório no GitHub, depois acessar a pasta *source* e depois executar o seguinte comando `gradle build`, e depois importar as **libs** para o projeto, porém na hora que eu executo o `gradle build` ele me retorna o seguinte erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém sabe como resolver?

Obs.: estou utilizando Ubuntu.

Link da descrição: https://github.com/pagseguro/pagseguro-java-sdk

Comment: Isso já aconteceu algo parecido comigo usando o gradle, porém, meu ambiente de desenvolvimento era diferente do seu. Estava usando a SDK do android studio. Resolvi instalando o JavaRuntime 6 (atual é o 8). Não desinstalei o 8, apenas instalei o 6. Tenta fazer isso, e se der certo, faça uma resposta a si mesmo detalhando tudo, para que outros não passem pelo mesmo problema.

Comment: Aqui ok, estou com openjdk 1.8.0_131. Só tive que incluir outros repositórios por que pelo padrão não resolveram algumas dependências. Tenta rodar com `--stacktrace` ou `--info` para ver se o log ajuda. Veja qual é o java no classpath e inclua na questão também